# Menu and text don't align despite Display Flex

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to reproduce this website to practice : https://www.arte.tv/fr/videos/documentaires-et-reportages/

I'm trying to create the nav bar and I don't know why the left line won't align on the same line, they ride on each other instead of being on the same line. The left part of the nav bar aligns on the same line, but the right part doesn't god know why.

I honestly start to feel kind of a shmuck, I've been on CSS 4 hours a day since one month, and I still can't do a darn navbar.

Here's my HTML and CSS :

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(221, 213, 213);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.arte-logo {
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-left ul {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-right ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Documentaires et reportages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/space/Arte/Assets/imgs/arte-icon.png"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img
              class="arte-logo"
              src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/space/Arte/Assets/imgs/arte-logo.png"
              alt="arte logo"
              ;
            />
          </li>
          <li><span>&#9783;</span></li>
          <li>Guide TV</li>
          <li>Direct</li>
          <li>Bientôt en ligne</li>
          <li>Arte Concert</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
          <li><span>&#9784;</span></li>
          <li><span>&#8853;</span></li>
          <div class="connecter">
            <li><span>&#9865;</span></li>
            <li>Se connecter</li>
          </div>
          <li>ARTE en 6 langues</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share an example, So we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, here's the website I'm trying to reproduce to practice : https://www.arte.tv/fr/videos/documentaires-et-reportages/ 
If you run my HTML file on the browser (I can't post screeshots) we can see that the left part of the navbar is not aligned, I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough that you have `align-items: center` on the navbar. That only aligns the `nav-left` and `nav-right` elements.
You need to also make sure that the elements that are inside those elements are aligned.

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(221, 213, 213);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.arte-logo {
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-left ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-right ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.connecter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Documentaires et reportages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/space/Arte/Assets/imgs/arte-icon.png"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-left">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img
              class="arte-logo"
              src="/Users/jeandizian/Documents/Code/space/Arte/Assets/imgs/arte-logo.png"
              alt="arte logo"
              ;
            />
          </li>
          <li><span>&#9783;</span></li>
          <li>Guide TV</li>
          <li>Direct</li>
          <li>Bientôt en ligne</li>
          <li>Arte Concert</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-right">
        <ul>
          <li><span>&#9784;</span></li>
          <li><span>&#8853;</span></li>
          <div class="connecter">
            <li><span>&#9865;</span></li>
            <li>Se connecter</li>
          </div>
          <li>ARTE en 6 langues</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```